# Creating a random fractional number in F#

Tags: f#, record

I was trying to create a random fractional number as follows:

```
type Fraction=
  {
  num: int
  den: int
  }

let makeRandomFraction i =
  let n= fun i -> System.Random(i).Next(-50, 51)
  let d= fun i -> System.Random(i*3).Next(-50, 51)
  {num=n; den=d}
```

but I am getting an error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int'
but here has type
    'int -> int'
```

Could you please explain the error and the correct way of doing the required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is saying that you're passing a function (of type `int -> int`) where an `int` is expected. You can see this more clearly in something like:

```
let add a b = a + b
let inc x = x + 1

inc add
//  ^^^
// This expression was expected to have type 'int' but has type 'int -> int -> int'
```

The solution here is just to take out the `fun i ->` parts. That's the (other) syntax for lambdas, but since your `i` variable is already in scope there's no need to create a function around it.

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, do you have any requirements on what range and distribution of fractions do you want your function to generate? The way the code is currently written - by composing two random numbers in a range -50 .. 50, you will get a distribution with most numbers being close to zero.

Here is a simple histogram built using the XPlot F# library:

[image: Distribution of random numbers]

```
open XPlot.GoogleCharts

type Fraction=
  { num: int
    den: int }

let makeRandomFraction i =
  let n = System.Random(i).Next(-50, 51)
  let d = System.Random(i*3).Next(-50, 51)
  {num=n; den=d}

[ for i in 0 .. 100000 -> let f = makeRandomFraction i in float f.num / float f.den ]
|> Seq.filter (System.Double.IsInfinity >> not)
|> Seq.countBy (fun f -> int f)
|> Chart.Column
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I want a ratio of two numbers, both ranging between -50 to 50.